# Pasting predefined text to specific row in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to paste a specific text with multiple lines to all .txt files containing in my D:\output folder

I'm listing all the.txt files stored under my output folder with these code;

```
import os

myDir = 'D:\output'

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(myDir):
    for file in f:
        if ".txt" in file:
            print(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Every .txt file has a section like that shown as below. I'd like to put my text block under this.

```
!**********************************************************************
!  Global parameters
!**********************************************************************
.
.
.
```

This is my multi-line text block

```
searchpath (1) = '.'
gravity (1) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (2) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (3) = -9.8100000000000005E+00 ! Gravity
vehicle.startvel= 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Vehicle initial velocity
vehicle.applystartvel= 0! Apply vehicle initial velocity at solver start
```

In the end, I would like to make my all files like these

```
!**********************************************************************
!  Global parameters
!**********************************************************************
searchpath (1) = '.'
gravity (1) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (2) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (3) = -9.8100000000000005E+00 ! Gravity
vehicle.startvel= 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Vehicle initial velocity
vehicle.applystartvel= 0! Apply vehicle initial velocity at solver start
.
.
.
```

Can anyone help me how can it be done with python? I'm a newbie about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to edit text files and add data in the middle, because they are sequential non-indexed files.

The common approach is to create a new temporary file and rewrite the whole txt the way you want, then delete the original and rename the new file to replace the old one.

The example below is untested, please back up your data.

```
text_to_find = '''\
!**********************************************************************
!  Global parameters
!**********************************************************************
'''

block_to_add = '''\
searchpath (1) = '.'
gravity (1) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (2) = 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Gravity
gravity (3) = -9.8100000000000005E+00 ! Gravity
vehicle.startvel= 0.0000000000000000E+00  ! Vehicle initial velocity
vehicle.applystartvel= 0! Apply vehicle initial velocity at solver start
'''

import os

myDir = r'D:\output'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(fullname) as f:
                data = f.read() # read the entire file to memory
            pos = data.find(text_to_find)  #locate the text
            if pos != -1: # found, insert the block
                 pos += len(text_to_find)
                 data = data[:pos] + block_to_add + data[pos:]
                 with open(fullname, 'w') as f:
                     f.write(data)   # rewrite the entire file
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i got an error like this   
`File "C:/PythonWorks/SearchPath/SearchPath.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = f.read() # read the entire file to memory
  File "C:\PythonWorks\SearchPath\venv\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 716412: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @Hakan It seems your encoding is off... what text encoding are the files using? try passing the correct encoding to the `open` call, as in:  `open(fullname, encoding='utf-8')`